# Can't integrate when solving this convolution question

Tags: integration, convolution

Suppose we have $f(t) = 1$ and $g(t) = 100\cos(20t)$.

Find $p(t) = f(t)*g(t)$.

***Solution***

$$(f*g)(t) = \int f(t-x)g(x)\,dx$$

$$f(t-x)=1$, $g(x)=100\cos(20x)$$

$$=100 \int \cos(20x)\,dx$$

$$p(t) = 5\sin(20t)$$

Now, when trying to do the other way around which is $p(t)=g(t)*f(t)$ I get stuck!

$$g(t-x)=100\cos[20(t-x)]=100\cos(20t-20x)$, $f(x)=1$$

$$(g*f)(t)= \int g(t-x)f(x)\,dx$$

$$=100 \int \cos(20t-20x)\,dx$$

Now what?